# Multiple <pre> blocks are not rendering correctly

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-preview, pre

[How to determine which NIC data/traffic is using?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100656/how-to-determine-which-nic-data-traffic-is-using/100658#100658)

My answer has two <pre> blocks in it. The first one came out OK, the 2nd one looks funky in the preview but still readable.

In the final answer, it's as if the <pre block isn't there.

[1 http://www.41085.org/pre-1.png](http://www.41085.org/pre-1.png)
[2 http://www.41085.org/pre-2.png](http://www.41085.org/pre-2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't encode the < as `&lt;` which was causing the sanitizer to reject that block.

Remember that within `<pre>` blocks you have to encode angle brackets.

Comment: Oooo, ok. I'd never put a < inside <pre> block before. Whoops.